# Periodically, dhcp4 trashes my wifi adapter's IP address

Tags: networking, wireless, dns, dhcp

A few times a day, I lose WiFi connectivity. When I have connectivity, the IP address of my wifi adaper is 192.168.0.93. When I don't have connectivity, the address is 172.20.20.20. syslog shows Network Manager dhcp4 setting this address.

I tried enabling manual adapter settings but my browser doesn't work, probably because I don't have a DNS server address entered.

How can I get dhcp4 to cooperate, or how can I properly do manual settings?

lspci says "Network Controller: Intel Wi-Fi 6 AX200 (rev 1a)

Comment: You sure your wifi network isn't the only one with that name being connected to?  The fact DHCP sets your network IPs to a completely different subnet is indicative of a false network being deployed, or some other badness being at play like conflicting DHCP on your network (you don't have a computer that is a DHCP server along with your router doing this do you?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest that you set a static IP address outside of the DHCP pool in the router. You can either look in the administrative pages of the router or, if this is not feasible, by guesswork. What do other computers, phones, iPads, etc. get for addresses. For example, if devices on the network get addresses like 192.168.0.4, 192.168.0.5, 192.168.0.7, etc. then I'd suggest a static IP address of 192.168.0.225.

Also, as you've seen, a proper DNS nameserver address(es) is required. I suggest the following, as an example:

[image]

Comment: The manual setting seems to work. In response to the other comment, the only other computer that could possibly be responding to DHCP requests in my Windows box, which has an Ethernet connection on the 192 subnet. I have no idea where the 172 address is coming from - could it be coming from my router?

Comment: I see that docker has a 172 address. I wonder if that app could have served up a 172 address for my wifi adapter to the dhcp client. I guess the question is academic since I'm using manual settings now.

Comment: If my answer has been helpful, please accept it: https://askubuntu.com/tour

Comment: The checkmark that should be there to accept your answer is not present